# how use in it in main project?

Tags: java

I have the following interface:

```
public interface MyFunctor {
   int myFunction(int x);
}
```

And I created a class which implements this interface :

```
public class Myfunction1 implements MyFunctor {
}
```

how use in main project? i have corrected mistake now i need how  run it in main   project?
i mean in `public static void main(String[]args)`?

Comment: You may want to tell us what language you're using.

Comment: Question has changed completely with last edit. Was how to implement a Java interface, is now how to implement a Java main() method. Rename or re-edit...

Comment: Question is very strange.
If u have interface realize it in any class. What does it mean: create method as same as in interface but with body.
If u want to use now what u wrote, then import your package with interface or class(i dont know what do u want) create instance of class and use it.

Comment: i have create interface and also class wihc implement methods  which are in interface now i want use these methods to solve ternary search problem

Comment: Sorry, but u question has changes every time u visit site. 
I wrote that if u have realization of interface in some class u need import package with class and then create instanse of class.

Comment: For ternary search problem create new question. i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you will need to provide implementation of the method defined in the `interface`.

To run your class, you will need to create an instance in your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFunction1 mf1 = new MyFunction1();
}
```

Alternatively, you could reference the var as the type of your interface:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFunctor mf = new MyFunction1();
}
```

To test your code in the implemented method, you will need to call the method on the new object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFunctor mf = new MyFunction1();
    int input = 5; //just for fun
    int output = mf.myFunction(input);
}
```

If you want to get fancy, you can pass the `input` var in on the commandline as an argument to your program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFunctor mf = new MyFunction1();
    int input = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); //you should include error handling
    int output = mf.myFunction(input);
}
```

Note that your `main` method can be contained in any `Class`, so you can implement it with your `MyFunction1` class.  To run it on the commandline, you would then use:

```
>java MyFunction1
```

This assumes you are in the dir where your `.class` file lives.

Answer (score 1):

It means, you need to implement every method described in the interfaces your class inherit from.

In your case:

```
public class Myfunction1 implements MyFunctor
{
  int myFunction(int x)
  {
    // Do whatever needs to be done here.

    return x; // Just so that it compiles.
  }
}
```

Comment: You will have to give us more information. Show us the exact compiler message and the code lines on which it complains.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the implementation. Otherwise, the statement that it *implements* MyFunctor is not true.

Example:

```
public class Myfunction1 implements MyFunctor{
  public int myFunction(int x) {
    return x+1; // or whatever you want to do with x..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
public class Myfunction1 implements MyFunctor {
  int myFunction(int x) {
    /* your code here */
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: What's the point of posting an answer when there is already two exact duplicates ?

Comment: @ereOn: Well, the "there is x new answers in this question" popup isn't real time and in questions like these where the easiest (although not the most correct) answer is fast to write, this happens.

Comment: @Esko Yeah, you're right. But 4 minutes to write such a fast answer seems long.